# Convert scalar function to a tensorflow Variable

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, tensorflow

I'm trying to optimize a pretty complicated function in tensorflow  where the last two layers of the function are:

```
dist = tf.contrib.distributions.Normal(mu = self._mu_pos[0][0], sigma=self._sig[0][0])
objective = a*dist.cdf(b)
```

where `a` and `b` are scalar values

However, since the variable `objective` is a scalar, I cannot use `train_op` as defined here:

```
opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01)

train_op = opt.minimize(objective_acq,var_list = [self._input])
```

This is because `opt.minimize` expects `objective` to be a tensorflow variable.

How can I convert `objective` to a tensorflow variable?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use tf.convert_to_tensor(), see documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/framework.html#convert_to_tensor).

Comment: I now get this error when I run train_op: TypeError: Argument is not a tf.Variable: Tensor("Mul:0", shape=(?, 1), dtype=float32)

Comment: Where is the error coming from? (At which function call?)

Comment: from sess.run(train_op)

Comment: No, the error is more upstream in the graph than that (it's a multiply op).  Not clear without the stack and full code, but what the error is saying is that there are some arguments that you passed to a multiply operations, that it expects to be a variable.  Hopefully this gives you something to debug on

Comment: Okay sorry my bad, the error I tihnk is coming from running train_op: `train_op = opt.minimize(objective_acq,var_list = [self._mu_pos])` .  Whatever I put into the 'var_list' field of my minimization function seems to return that error, where the error is referring to the variable I give to 'var_list'. Well, apparently it isn't a variable at all. How do I then convert the intermediate "variables" of my graph to tensorflow Variables?

Comment: You can try putting the var_list argument into a tf.Variable, as described here: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/how_tos/variables/index.html

Comment: thanks! But how can I do this for the input placeeholder? I really wanna do the optimization for the input placeholder for my graph, which isn't a tf Variable

Comment: Okay, I've narrowed it down to my placeholder having a dynamic shape (which I need for some other use of my graph), so I cannot create a (1x1) duplicate of my placeholder (which I need for the optimization) using tf.Variable(placeholder_name). Is there a way to be able to use my placeholder as a 1x1 Variable unless I make my placeholder 1x1?